# How powerful does an electric field have to be to attract carbon dioxide?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields

I was reading about a Van de Graaff generator and I was curious to know if it can attract air. Specifically, if an electric field is powerful enough, can it attract carbon dioxide?

Answer (score 0):

CO2 molecule is nonpolar, but it acquires an electric dipole moment in electric field. If the electric field is also nonuniform, it can attract CO2 molecules.

Comment: But if there is a distance of 4 inches, how powerful does the electric field have to be?

Comment: @AakarshTathachar : I gave you a hint. Why don't you calculate that yourself?

Comment: I'm sorry for bothering you again, but I'm really new to this and I am still wondering what equation I should use, I know you were hinting at the dipole moment, but it would be great if you could just give the equation I should use.